# My tc script just limit outgoing traffic or both outgoing and incoming traffic?

Tags: qos, tc

I create this script to limit bandwidth all traffic through card eth1, I can test download speed with wget command but don't know how to test upload speed. Can anyone answer my question or show me how to test upload speed? Thanks for your help!

```
#/bin/sh
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 10
sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 150kbps ceil 150kbps
```

Comment: Umm...upload something to a remote system??!?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try uploading to remote host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test accurately, you could use a [public iperf server](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php), with an iperf client on your computer.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I can't connect to any iperf public server. Can you help me? My command: iperf bouygues.testdebit.info -p 5200

Comment: Try with `iperf -c bouygues.testdebit.info -p 5200` to specify you are running iperf as a client.